# Selenium: How to relate an id or a class to a specific div?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, highcharts, katalon-recorder

I tried to search before asking but I didn't find (or understand) the right answer for my issue.

I'm testing some charts (powered by Highcharts 6). I have 6 different charts on the same url. Each one is in a `div` container which has the different elements inside it (buttons, etc.).

The class and/or ID for all the buttons are the same.
For example, this is the Maximize/Minimize button for chart1:

```
<a class="has-tooltip btn btn-default change" role="button" title="" id="table" data-original-title="TEXT">
<span class="fa fa-lg ik-wi-icon-th"></span></a>
```

And here is the same button for chart2:

```
<a class="has-tooltip btn btn-default change" role="button" title="" id="table" data-original-title="TEXT">
<span class="fa fa-lg ik-wi-icon-th"></span></a>
```

They are exactly the same. So I tried to use Katalon Recorder to figure out how it can notice that I am clicking different buttons and this is what I get:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='table']/span")).click(); click1
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='table']/span")).click(); click2

driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@id='table']/span)[2]")).click(); click1
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@id='table']/span)[2]")).click(); click2
```

Where did this `[2]` come from?
How can tell Selenium which button I want to click?

Comment: I have added the `katalon-studio` tag to your question. Possibly someone more familiar with `katalon-studio` will be able to guide you better.

Comment: [Check this guide on HTML](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/classid/). IDs used in HTML tags must be unique, as they are used to identify precisely one of your DOM element. Here they are tagged as `table`. If you want to identify multiple DOM elements, use your `class` instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick answer! Hopefully someone who has mastered katalon could help me! About the class and ID, all the buttons are in the same HTML, with same class and ID as you can see in the code i have posted, so how can i difference them? still same question...

Comment: @GinoMempin Any reason to drop the tag `katalon-studio` where as OP's question is based on **Katalon Recorder**? Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, actually is not based on katalon since you can get exactly the same output using selenium IDE, but as long as we are talking about testing, i thought was more related with selenium. Sorry if i brought confussion here

Comment: @DebanjanB Hmm..I did not deliberately remove the tag you added, I'm sure I only edited the contents. I did get a message though that someone else made an edit and my edit will only be saved if it was more "substantial". I'm not sure, maybe SO *incorrectly merged* our edits? In any case, I'm sorry if my edit removed your tag. (I have no rep to put it back immediately though).

Comment: Perhaps you can use index if the identifiers are same. Ex : driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@id='table']/span)[2]")).click(); to click the 2nd button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `2` came from, DOM wise, the second `//a[@id='table']/span` in the HTML.

Lets say you have 6 graphs, and they all have a link with `id='table'` and they all have a span under it, this means that  `//a[@id='table']/span` is going to return 6 elements. With xpath, **only when you are sure that the sequence of your graphs is not going to change**, you can say that to click the first graph:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='table']/span")).click();
```

Second:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@id='table']/span)[2]")).click();
```

Third:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@id='table']/span)[3]")).click();
```

etc.

To be absolutely sure, hit F12 in chrome while on the page you want to test. Then go to Console, and typ:

```
$x("//a[@id='table']/span")
```

It will probably return 6 elements. When you open each of these elements and mouse-over them, Chrome will highlight the element it has found. Now if you want the fifth element Chrome found, typ this in console:

```
$x("(//a[@id='table']/span)[5]")
```

And now see if the element returned is the fifth on the page.

Comment: Thank you so much!!